# How to detect covariant type arguments in Scala AST

Tags: scala

Suppose that I have the AST for the following Scala code:

```
class Foo
class Bar(val s: Seq[_ <: Foo])
```

If `t` is the Type of `Bar.s`, I find that

```
t.typeArgs.head.bounds.lo == t.typeArgs.head.bounds.hi
```

I also find that

```
t.typeArgs.head.bounds.lo.typeSymbol.isCovariant == false
```

How do I detect that `s` is defined as `Seq[_ <: Foo]` rather than `Seq[Foo]`?

Comment: Is there any difference? `scala> new Bar(Seq(new Baz, new Quoz))` => 
`res2: Bar = Bar@17497425` given Baz and Quoz extending Foo. Are you trying to make Bar contain only a single subtype of Foo?

Comment: Specifically `_ <: Foo` means "Foo or any subclass of Foo"` while `Foo` means... "Foo or any subclass of Foo". I'd be surprised if in this case it resulted in any different code

Comment: @Daenyth This is only correct if `Foo` is in a covariant position. For example, you can put a `Foo` into an `Array[Foo]`, but not into an `Array[_ <: Foo]`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Good point. At least as far as it comes to the OP's example, `new Bar(Seq(new Foo))` works